# Find row with lowest value in COLUMNA, return row's COLUMNB

Tags: r

I have a feeling this is one of those stupidly easy things where I'm just not using a function I should be.

Here's the relevant part of the function:

```
min(DATASET$COLUMNNAME, na.rm = TRUE)
```

Right now, it reports the correct value from COLUMNNAME--the lowest value in that column. Great. However, what I *really* want it to do is look across the dataframe to that result's entry in column NAME and print that. It should not print the minimum value at all, just the entry in NAME for the row with COLUMNAME's minimum value.

Is the best way to do it to get the row number of that minimum value somehow, and return DATASET$NAME[row,] ?

Comment: just remove that comma at the end

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Looking for this maybe:

```
DATASET$NAME[DATASET$COLUMNNAME == min(DATASET$COLUMNNAME)]
```

That is, you select `NAME` from `DATASET`, where `COLUMNAME` has the minimum value.

If you don't like repeating `DATASET` so many times, this is equivalent using `with`:

```
with(DATASET, NAME[COLUMNNAME == min(COLUMNNAME)])
```

Comment: That did it! I'd give you an upvote, but I don't have the rep yet.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 24):

The function you are looking for is `which.min`:

```
> set.seed(123)
> df<-data.frame(name=sample(LETTERS[1:10]),value=sample(10))
> df
   name value
1     C    10
2     H     5
3     D     6
4     G     9
5     F     1
6     A     7
7     J     8
8     I     4
9     B     3
10    E     2
> df[which.min(df$value),]
  name value
5    F     1
> df$name[which.min(df$value)]
[1] F
Levels: A B C D E F G H I J
```

Comment: What if there are two rows with value 1 and I would like to have them both?